# jquery plugin add public method

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

i'm writting a simple slider plugin just to learn a little jquery and maybe use for my own projects.

The slider works fine but i want to add some public methods like goToSlide(x) and i don't know how to  create that public methods.

You have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oterox/vvZqj/1/)

i was trying something like:

```
var slideto = function(position){
    gotoslide(position);
};
```

right now i use the plugin like this:

```
$('#home-slider').pxslider({
    slideWidth: 300,
    speed: 500,
    onSlideBefore: function(){
                $('p.debug span').html('starting animation');
            },
    onSlideAfter: function(){
                $('p.debug span').html('stop animation');
            }

    });
```

and i would like to do somethig like:

```
$('#home-slider').pxslider().gotoslide(x);
or
$('#home-slider').pxslider('gotoslide','x');
```

jsfiddle with the sample code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oterox/vvZqj/1/)

Comment: Did you find any solution yet? I am as well trying to achieve something like "$('#htmlid').myplugin().publicmethod(x);".

Comment: yes, i've rewritten the code.Take a look at it https://github.com/oterox/jquery.pxslider

Answer (score 0):

I finally created a plugin with new code.

https://github.com/oterox/jquery.pxslider

Now everything works like i wanted.